# StructureMap: 'AddAllTypesOf' not adding assembly to ObjectFactory?

Tags: c#, structuremap, .net-assembly

I am trying to build a console app that loads an assembly at runtime which implements an interface. The point is to create a .dll with instructions that can be changed by changing the .dll.

My VS2012 solution exists of 3 projects: the interface, a library which implements it, and a console app. (Because of this, all three have their own namespace, maybe this is a problem?) The library and console app both have references to the interface project.

After adding the assemblies to the `ObjectFactory`, they are not found when using `GetAllInstances`. They are found when using `AssembliesFromPath`, but the adding does not seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
var dir = "..\\..\\..\\ComputeLibrary\\bin\\Debug";
ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.AssembliesFromPath(dir);
        scanner.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(ICompute)).NameBy(i => i.Name);
    });
});
var list = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<ICompute>().ToList();
list.ForEach(item => item.Test());
```

In case anyone want to look at the entire solution, it is available [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1168498/Uploaded/LoadLibrary.zip).

I'm probably doing something wrong here, but I can't seem to find what it is.
Is this how it's supposed to be used? Or should I look towards MEF for doing something like this?

Comment: According to the documentation your code appears to be in line with what is expected. You've ran this in the debugger with a breakpoint and verified that the scanner instance has the expected assembly after the `scanner.AssembliesFromPath(dir);` line executes?

Comment: Yes, after running that line, the scanner contains 2 assemblies: the interface and the library whereas before that, there are 0. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Z0znR0Y.png)

Comment: What happens if you eliminate the `.NameBy`? I'm wondering if maybe there is an exception getting swallowed that's preventing the classes from getting added to the scanner.

Comment: removing that part doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This puzzled me for a while, until I remembered [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/structuremap-users/c64UWzdmv7E) in the Structuremap google group.

When you run your application, the ComputeInterface.dll assembly is loaded. When you scan the ComputeLibrary folder, the same assembly is loaded again and this is confusing Structuremap, since the interface can only be implemented from one assembly. Try deleting the ComputeInterface.dll from the ComputeLibrary\bin\Debug folder and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, deleting the interface dll did indeed solve the problem.I never would have come up with that.